# Type mismatch 13 on one computer but not another - Different versions of excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a code which was tested and working find on my computer, I also tested this on a colleagues computer and it worked fine. I have since sent to another 2 colleagues for testing and it is failing with a Type Mismatch 13 error.

When I have debugged the error it highlights the following code as being the error. I have done numerous searches and checked the language code to see if that is causing the issue (it is not). I have also checked and from what I see the only difference is I am on Office 365 & they are on Office 2016, Both machines are 32-bit.

```
Dim Actions as Range
' ...
Set PTCache1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Actions)
```

I'm hoping to be able to detect the true reason for the error and if it is a comparability error then create an **IF Then** statement which can detect for the difference and choose the code based on this?

Comment: Would you please trim the code down to an example we can try that shows the error in your environment?  There's a decent chance that the problem is the use of `ActiveWorkbook` - try using explicitly-assigned `Workbook` variables and see if the problem goes away.  For version testing, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.version , but you probably won't need it

Comment: What is `Actions`?  The docs say not to use a`Range` object.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create

Comment: Actions is a range and is declared as a range. I am trying your suggestion about changing from ActiveWorkbook to a declared workbook.

Comment: :) Also pass a string representation of `Actions` to Create as the docs suggest.

Answer (score 1):

- Replace `Actions` with `Actions.Address`.  The docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create say:

> When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly.

- Instead of `ActiveWorkbook`, use `Workbook` variables that you Dim and assign.  Using any of the `Active*` variables requires you and Excel to always agree on what is active, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: So I tried to the following 2 methods first one 
`Set PTCache1 = ActionWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, ActionOverview.Range("A7:S" & LastRow)) ` which worked for me as before but still failed with the same error for my colleague. 

I have then changed to 'Actions.Address' and this now gives me the following error - _The PivotTable Field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns. If you are changing the name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field._  Any help?

Comment: The error now comes from code `CountryDash.PivotTables.Add(PTCache1, CtyDrng)`  looking at the Locals window the Source Data shows as ??????? but when it is  `Actions` on the PTCache1 it gives the range of the original data range. Any idea?